# Двойной вызов триггера

Tags: javascript, jquery

`transitransitionend` вызывается 2 раза, не могу понять почему.

```js
$("#t").click(function(){
  $("#d").toggleClass("asd");
});

$(".asd").on("transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEndtionend", function(){
  alert(123)
});
```

```css
.asd {
  display:block;
  transition: all .2s;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}

div:not(.asd) {
  height:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="t">test</button>
<div class="asd" id="d">asdasfasd</div>
```

Comment: может просто transitionend ? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Events/transitionend

Comment: а у вас transi + transitionend

Comment: oTransitionEnd + tionend - вот косяк

Comment: @MaximLensky не...все дело в `transition` `css`было. ps. ` transi + transitionend` очепятка (копипаста)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твоя ошибка в том, что ты указал
 `transition: all .2s;`
но в своем коде ты меняешь только `height`
сделай  `transition: height .2s;` вместо all.
И в целом старайся всегда уточнять, какой именно транзишн ты собираешься анимировать.

```js
$("#t").click(function(){
  $("#d").toggleClass("asd");
});

$(".asd").on("transitionend MSTransitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEndtionend", function(){
  alert(123)
});
```

```css
.asd {
  display:block;
  transition: height .2s;
  background-color: red;
  height: 400px;
}

div:not(.asd) {
  height:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="t">test</button>
<div class="asd" id="d">asdasfasd</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, не знал о таком ньюансе